# bin-dir does not get ignored with SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I am working on a project using Eclipse 4.19.0. I also have Subclipse installed. However I started using TortoiseSVN 1.10. I have ignored files in a nested project (`trunk > subproject > right click > TortoiseSVN > Properties`) like:

[image]

However, if I `trunk > right click > Commit`, changes in subproject/bin/someFolder does still get shown. Weirdly the ignore works for subproject/build/*.

Any idea what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a file has been commited to SVN then it doesn't matter if it is ignored or not. It will be handled like any other file you have checked out from the SVN repository.

So if you want to ignore files that have already been committed to SVN you first have to delete them from SVN.

TortoiseSVN has a functionality that combines deleting the file in SVN (but keeping it locally) and adding it to ignore list:

`Unversion and add to ignore list`:

[image: TortoiseSVN Unversion and add to ignore list operation]

The other ways like deleting the file locally and commit it or delete the file in SVN via SVN repo browser will end up in the local file being deleted. So you chose this way make sure to first copy the local files to a backup location so that you are able to restore the file(s) once the delete operation has been applied.

Comment: Thanks. There was indeed an empty bin-folder in the repo. I got confused, because Subclipse somehow did ignore according to svn-ignore, while TortoiseSVN was not (like I should except it)